# Why did my navbar stop working when I switched to Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
HTML
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
         <a href="#top">Top</a>
         <a href="#middle">Middle</a>
         <a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>

        <ul id="navigation_bar">
            <li id="top"><a href="top"></a>Top</li>
            <li id="middle"><a href="middle"></a>Middle</li>
            <li id="bottom"><a href="bottom"></a>Bottom</li>
    </nav>
</div>

CSS
#top, #middle, #bottom {
height: 600px;
width: 200px;
background: green; 
text-decoration: none;
}

body {
padding-top: 70px;
}
```

---

I added the 'fix to top' HTML code provided by this link: https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

Can someone tell me why my nav bar ceased to function after I did this?

Thank you

Comment: You have an unclosed `</ul>` tag.. Idk if that's contributing to your issues or not..

Comment: Have you loaded the bootstrap javascript as well as the bootstrap css libraries?

Comment: Also.. describe your desired behavior, and describe the current behavior. It is extremely hard when you say "why did this cease to function?" That's a pretty good way to get a question removed

Comment: @elethan the OP doesn't have to have the JS included in the file as the fixed navigation bar (`navbar-fixed-top`) is pure CSS.

Comment: Are you trying to create a navigation that will jump to different sections of the page? If so, you cannot have the section of the website you wish to jump to encapsulated within the `nav` tag.

Answer (score 0):

After looking more into this, your HTML doesn't make very much sense.

The way I see it is:

```
<ul id="navigation_bar">
    <li id="top"><a href="top"></a>Top</li> // <-- <a> tag with a meaningless href and no innerText
    <li id="middle"><a href="middle"></a>Middle</li>
    <li id="bottom"><a href="bottom"></a>Bottom</li>
</ul>
```

My only guess is that you are trying to use the above code as your content sections?

In which case, you would need to move your closing `</nav>` tag above that code to look like so:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <a href="#top">Top</a>
      <a href="#middle">Middle</a>
      <a href="#bottom">Bottom</a>
    </nav>

    <ul id="navigation_bar">
      <li id="top"><a href="#top"></a>Top</li>
      <li id="middle"><a href="#middle"></a>Middle</li>
      <li id="bottom"><a href="#bottom"></a>Bottom</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing, not sure why there are two sets of links.  I usually use the nav from http://getbootstrap.com/examples/starter-template/ instead of https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar.  I believe it's the same thing with more detailed code where the ellipses are on your link.  Here is a nav using most of your code based on the template from my link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <style>
    #top, #middle, #bottom {
    height: 600px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
    body {
    padding-top: 70px;
    }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li id="top" class="active"><a href="top">Top</a></li>
        <li id="middle"><a href="middle">Middle</a></li>
        <li id="bottom"><a href="bottom">Bottom</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



  </body>
</html>
```